# Data fetching in Next Js is showing undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch my data from https://openweathermap.org/ in my Content component but the data fetched is show undefined. If I fetch the data from index.js page then I am getting the data but not in Content.js

Here is my code:

```
Content.getInitialProps = async function () {
  const res = await fetch(
    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Darjeeling&appid=28ed2c46c8acdc29953d"
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  
  return {
    weather: data,
  };
};
```

When I am trying to console log data inside `Content` function via props
Here is a small code of how I am consoling data:

```
const Content=(props)=>{
console.log(props.weather);
}
```

Its logging undefined.

Comment: Can you do console.log(data)? Do you get undefined there too?

Comment: it will give an error if I do console.log(data) as I am fetching data in next JS using getInitialProps and weather is outside Content function.

Comment: Is your Content component in the pages folder?

Comment: pages>components>Content.js This is my path to Content.js

Comment: So your url to that page is url.com/components/content ?
Also try using a arrow function for getInitialProps. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages

Comment: You can't use `getInitialProps` from components, it's only available from pages. Also, your components should not be under the `pages/` folder as that folder is used for routing purposes by Next.js.

Comment: Thanks, @juliomalves I figured it.

Comment: @juliomalves is there any way to fetch data from components in nextjs

Comment: You can fetch data inside the component's `useEffect` (client-side), or you can fetch data from the parent page (server-side) and pass it down to the component.